# Unable to add a pop acount to free gmail account

Tags: gmail, ionos

I have been using the same pop account for years (decades) with gmail - I had some issues and deleted the account and now I am unable to add any new service to my gmail account.
Anyone else having these issues?

I literaly put in the information from IONOS as pop server and my email address and password together with the provided port number and security etc

But it just doesnt save into gmail so when I next go and check settings, nothing is there!

all help greatly appreciated

[image]